# Grammar Rule for Math Expressions (No Left-Recursion)

Tags: syntax, expression, grammar, ebnf

I'm trying to figure out a grammar rule(s) for any mathematical expression.

I'm using EBNF (wiki article linked below) for deriving syntax rules.

I've managed to come up with one that worked for a while, but the grammar rule fails with `onScreenTime + (((count) - 1) * 0.9)`.

The rule is as follows:

```
math ::= MINUS? LPAREN math RPAREN
       | mathOperand (mathRhs)+

mathRhs ::= mathOperator mathRhsGroup
          | mathOperator mathOperand mathRhs?

mathRhsGroup ::= MINUS? LPAREN mathOperand (mathRhs | (mathOperator mathOperand))+ RPAREN
```

You can safely assume `mathOperand` are positive or negative numbers, or variables.
You can also assume `mathOperator` denotes any mathematical operator like + or -.

Also, `LPAREN` and `RPAREN` are '(' and ')' respectively.

EBNF:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form

**EDIT**
Forgot to mention that it fails on `(count) - 1`. It says `RPAREN` expected instead of `- 1`.

**EDIT 2** My revised EBNF now looks like this:

```
number ::= NUMBER_LITERAL //positive integer

mathExp ::= term_ ((PLUS | MINUS) term_)* // * is zero-or-more.

private term_ ::= factor_ ((ASTERISK | FSLASH) factor_)*

private factor_ ::= PLUS factor_
                  | MINUS factor_
                  | primary_

private primary_ ::= number
                   | IDENTIFIER
                   | LPAREN mathExp RPAREN
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the expression grammar of any programming language:

```
expression
    : term
    | expression '+' term
    | expression '-' term
    ;

term
    : factor
    | term '*' factor
    | term '/' factor
    | term '%' factor
    ;

factor
    : primary
    | '-' factor
    | '+' factor
    ;

primary
    : IDENTIFIER
    | INTEGER
    | FLOATING_POINT_LITERAL
    | '(' expression ')'
    ;
```

Exponentiation left as an exercise for the reader: note that the exponentiation operator is right-associative. This is in *yacc* notation. NB You are using EBNF, not BNF.

**EDIT** My non-left-recursive EBNF is not as strong as my `yacc`, but to factor out the left-recursions you need a scheme like for example:

```
expression
    ::= term ((PLUS|MINUS) term)*
term
    ::= factor ((FSLASH|ASTERISK) factor)*
```

etc., where `*` means 'zero or more'. My comments on this below are mostly incorrect and should be ignored.

Comment: This is magnificent and I see how it works, but unfortunately my generator doesn't allow "left recursion". How could I modify this such that there isn't left recursion?

Comment: Just change it to `expression: term '+' term` etc

Comment: Doing so doesn't allow all expressions though. For example, 2 * (3 * 3) + 1 + 1 fails.

Comment: Fails how? How are you *implementing* this grammar?

Comment: I'm making a custom language plugin for Intellij IDE. Basically, I type in the grammar and click a button to generate the parser code. The parser code then creates an AST. The parser tells me where it expects certain tokens, like a Java compiler.

Comment: Well you're going to have to provide more information than that. You'll have to show me what your EBNF looks like for a start. You can see for yourself that this is a correct grammar: you will find it in the language specifications for Algol, Pascal, C, C++, Java, and who knows where else. I've used it many times. You could try making it *right*-recursive if you don't mind the associativity being wrong.

Comment: `number ::= (MINUS)? NUMBER_LITERAL` is wrong for a start. The grammar above already handles unary minus and plus. Just do it the way I did. Don't post material relevant to your question on external websites.

Comment: Unfortunately each way you have suggested doesn't work. My grammar isn't allowed to have left recursion, therefore your first answer doesn't work. I replaced parts where left recursion was with what you suggested and that didn't work 100% (1+1+1 doesn't work for example), therefore your 2nd suggestion doesn't work. What I need is a non-left recursion expression rule.  Perhaps we should move the discussion to chat?

Comment: Unfortunately you invented a `number` rule that I didn't give you, and as a result it doesn't work. Try it my way.

Comment: I'm using number::= NUMBER_LITERAL    NUMBER_LITERAL is strictly positive integers.                                                                                         1+1+1 still fails. On the second +, it says it's expecting '*', '/', or ';'

Comment: You need repetition rules to replace the missing recursions, e.g. `expression ::= term (PLUS term)+`.

Comment: I added in the repetition rules and you can see what I have in my question under "**EDIT 2**". 1 + 1 + 1 passes now, but 1 * 1 / 1 + 2 does not (expecting '*','-','+',';' on '/'). Doing `(PLUS factor_)+` instead of `PLUS factor_` along with the minus one had no effect.

Comment: The **Edit** works for every expression I throw at it. But for some reason I can do 1+++++++++++1 or 1++1 or 1------1. I updated the revised edit in my question.

Comment: The reason is that it's perfectly legal mathematically. If 1 is legal, so is +1, and therefore so is ++1. If you don't want to allow it, change the `factor` rule accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the expression grammar of languages that are typically implemented using recursive descent parsers for which LL(1) grammars are needed which do not allow left recursion. Most if not all of Wirth's languages fall into this group. Below is an example from the grammar of classic Modula-2. EBNF links are shown next to each rule.

http://modula-2.info/m2pim/pmwiki.php/SyntaxDiagrams/PIM4NonTerminals#expression